# Web deployment task failed (Could not complete the request to remote agent URL https://xx.publish.azurewebsites.windows.net/msdeploy.axd?site=XXXXXXX)

Tags: linux, azure-web-app-service, blazor-server-side, azure-appservice

I am trying to publish blazor server web application to azure linux app service via visual studio community version 16.9.5
But it is failing with error information below:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error     Web deployment task failed. (Could not complete the request to
> remote agent URL
> 'https://XXXXXXX.publish.azurewebsites.windows.net/msdeploy.axd?site=XXXXXXX-dev__staging'.)
>
> Could not complete the request to remote agent URL
> 'https://XXXXXX.publish.azurewebsites.windows.net/msdeploy.axd?site=XXXXXX-dev__staging'.
> The operation has timed out   xxxxxx.web      0

I faced this issue earlier also but after one or two retry it was getting solved automatically. but this time I  am unable to publish it after more than 20 tries. there is no exact information on exact problem anywhere.

Please suggest me if any exact cause of the error or solution.

Thanks,
Ashish

Answer (score 1):

**Troubleshooting:**

1. Maybe you can try to set `WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM=false` on portal.

   For more details, you can refer this post.

   [Why is application deployment failing on waws-prod-blu-167.publish.azurewebsites.windows.net?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/13993/why-is-application-deployment-failing-on-waws-prod.html)
2. In contrast, when using vs2019 was previously released, whether Service Dependencies were added.

   *Check whether the configuration of Service Dependencies is correct.*

   [image]
3. If all the above methods fail, please download publish profile and import to vs2019, then retry to publish your app.

   [image]

Comment: I tried all of them but it didn't helped.

Comment: @Ashish Can you create a new webapp and deploy it.  Check whether the project can be successfully published in the new webapp? What I need to determine is whether the project has been modified recently that caused the release exception.

Comment: I am facing this error randomly. And there is multiple ways to make it solve but it is not guaranteed. Sometimes It gets solved by rebuilding & cleaning solution. Some time restarting visual studio solves it. or sometime recreating publish profile from scratch solves it. So I don't think it is issue with any project related changes.

Comment: @Ashish Is the same computer used for each release?